# C++: With two identical functions, one gives an error. What is happening?

Tags: c++, identifier

Something strange is happening. Using MVS 2013.

Filename.cpp

```
#include "Functions.h"
int main()
{
    introInformation();
    introInformation2();
}
```

Functions.cpp

```
void introInformation()
{
//A bunch of couts telling the user how to play the game.
}

void introInformation2()
{
//A bunch of couts telling the user how to play the game.
}
```

When introInformation2() is called in main. MVS gives the error: 'introInformation2': identifier not found. But why only the second? Everything appears to be identical.

Stranger yet, when I make a function declaration above main for just introInformation2() everything works fine. But at the same time there is no declaration for introInformation().

I've noticed that if I change the name of introInformation() to introInformation1() (yes, in the function call and the definition) I get the same error. It seems like MVS is set on the previous name.

I've got a slight suspicion that this is happening because I copy-pasted this original project and worked on possible changes without changing the pasted project's folder name. That new project has since been deleted.

Comment: What's the contents of `Functions.h`?

Comment: The code you have shown us is correct. The error is within the code you have not shown.

Comment: What is the content of `Functions.h` ? Does it declare `introInformation()` ?

Comment: it seems you have not include void introInformation2() in "Functions.h"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Vlad, Christian Hacki, Jarod42 and kiviak.
Most likely checking the content of Functions.h will show that introInformation() has been declared, but introInformation2() has not.

Comment: Ahh geez, I'm embarrassed. This is correct.